# Send list of query parameters to jersey client using GET in jersey 2.x?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-client

In jersey version 1.4 (at least that's the only reference I can find online) there was `com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource` where you could send a list of parameters using Webresource.queryParams() ... seems that method no longer exists in jersey-client 2.x ... I imagine it's still possible to do this (without having to manually put together a query string)? There is class WebTarget with a method:

`public WebTarget queryParam(String name, Object... values);`

but no queryParams() method.

Answer (score 6):

Just call queryParam() multiple times. Such as

```
target.queryParam("foo", "fooValue").queryParam("bar", "barValue");
```

or in case you have a map you can loop through the entries:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    target = target.queryParam(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Anything if you already have a map?  e.g. .queryParams(params)

Comment: See here https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.4/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/WebResource.html#queryParams(javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap)

Comment: @Sebastain, but that is not for the jersey 2.x.x line?

Comment: Yes. Please ignore my utterly stupid comment (should delete it but then your 2nd comment makes no sense anymore). I adapted my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `public WebTarget queryParam(String name, Object... values);` method:

```
target.queryParam("foo", "fooValue", "barValue", "anythingElseValue");
```

If you do have a List already, just pass that as a plain array:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("foo");
list.add("bar");

target.queryParam("foo", list.toArray());
```